# Is it possible to programmatically dismiss the Touch ID LAContext dialog?

Tags: ios, touch-id

In the event that my app receives a push notification while the touch ID dialog is on screen, I'd like to be able to cancel/dismiss it and handle the push.

Is this possible, or do I need to either store the push data until the user causes the dialog to dismiss or schedule a replacement local push to handle it later?

Comment: The touchID dialog is not presented (directly) by your app - it is presented by iOS when you request it. You will receive a call to `didResignActive` `didBecomeActive` in your app delegate when the touchID dialog is presented/dismissed.  Perhaps you can use this to determine your application state and process the notification appropriately

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, the documentation of `LAContext`'s `invalidate()` method states that a call to this function causes any currently in-progress authentication to fail via the `systemCancel` error code.

So when you get a notification, you can invalidate your local authentication context. Note that once invalidated, a context may not be reused.

Comment: But this method is only available from iOS 9.0, so there is no solution for apps with build target 8.0 and higher?

Comment: Not that I’m aware of.